# C# FetchAsync and delegate call in method

Tags: c#

```
/// <summary>
/// Delegate for executing an asynchronous request.
/// </summary>
public delegate void ExecuteRequestDelegate<T>(LazyResult<T> response);

public void FetchAsync([Optional] ExecuteRequestDelegate<TResponse> methodToCall)
        {
            GetAsyncResponse(
                (IAsyncRequestResult state) =>
                    {
                        var result = new LazyResult<TResponse>(() =>
                                {
                                    // Retrieve and convert the response.
                                    IResponse response = state.GetResponse();
                                    return FetchObject(response);
                                });

                        // Only invoke the method if it was set.
                        if (methodToCall != null)
                        {
                            methodToCall(result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result.GetResult();
                        }
                    });
        }
```

I want to call now `FetchAsync` but I don't know how

```
service.Userinfo.Get().FetchAsync(new ExecuteRequestDelegate<Userinfo>() {...});
```

and I get back that ExecuteRequestDelegate does not contain an constructor that takes 0 arguments.

What can I do? I want to get `Userinfo` data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FetchAsync`'s parameter is a method that accepts a `LazyResult` as it's only parameter and that returns `void`.  This is consistent with the general patter of a "callback" method, which is one way of writing an asynchronous method.  In order to be asynchronous this method will return immediately after being called, and when the operation it logically represents *actually* finishes, it will call your callback method, passing in the results of the asynchronous operation as the parameter to the callback.

While you could write out a named method to handle this case, it's often appropriate to use a lambda here:

```
service.Userinfo.Get().FetchAsync(
    lazyResult => Console.WriteLine(lazyResult.Result));
```

If you have more than a line or so of code, then it's worth taking the time to use a named method:

```
public void ProcessResult(LazyResult<Userinfo> result)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

---

```
service.Userinfo.Get().FetchAsync(ProcessResult);
```

Comment: Superb. Thank yolu for explanation